# SQL: creating a new column based on conditions in two other columns in a dataset with repeated observations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for some help creating a new column in a view based on the attributes of other columns in the dataset I'm working with that looks like this:

```
    Prop| Amenity|Rank | Date     |

    A   | Paper  | 1   | 1/1/2000 |
    A   | Pen    | 1   | 1/1/2000 |
    A   | Paper  | 2   | 12/1/1999|
    A   | Pen    | 2   | 12/1/1999|
    B   | Paper  | 1   | 1/1/2002 |
    B   | Pen    | 1   | 1/1/2002 |
    B   | Paper  | 2   | 1/1/1999 |
    B   | Pen    | 2   | 1/1/1999 |
    B   | Ruler  | 2   | 1/1/1999 |
```

I'm trying to create an additional column that is populated with the date of the most recent rank (i.e. date where[Rank]=1) for each property type (A, B, etc.). The desired outcome would look like this

```
   Prop | Amenity|Rank | Date     | Rank1date|

    A   | Paper  | 1   | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2000 |
    A   | Pen    | 1   | 1/1/2000 | 1/1/2000 |
    A   | Paper  | 2   | 12/1/1999| 1/1/2000 |
    A   | Pen    | 2   | 12/1/1999| 1/1/2000 |
    B   | Paper  | 1   | 1/1/2002 | 1/1/2002 |
    B   | Pen    | 1   | 1/1/2002 | 1/1/2002 |
    B   | Paper  | 2   | 1/1/1999 | 1/1/2002 |
    B   | Pen    | 2   | 1/1/1999 | 1/1/2002 |
    B   | Ruler  | 2   | 1/1/1999 | 1/1/2002 |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I need to clarify the question or provide additional information.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: added tag as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*, 
       max(case when rank = 1 then date end) over (partition by prop) as rank1date
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this and you saved me a bunch of time and brow furrowing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way of address this involves a join of a table to a query like this..  This would be useful if you come across a situation where window functions where not available, or if you wanted for some reason to avoid window functions.

```
create view v1 as 
Select 
  t1.prop, t1.amenity, t1.rank, t1.date, subq.rank1date from
  (select prop, max(date) as rank1date from t1 where rank = 1 group by prop) subq
  join t1 
    on t1.prop = subq.prop
```